# Given $F(x) = \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x,t) dt$ exists and is finite for all x, prove $F(x)$ is continuous if $f(x,t)$ is also continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a function $f:\mathbf{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ such that $f(x,t)$ is continuous and bounded on $\mathbf{R} \times [a, +\infty)$. Define $F(x) = \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x,t)\, dt$, and say I know $F(x)$ exists and is finite for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$.

Is this enough to say $F(x)$ is continuous? If so, any advice for how I would prove it? And if not, what other criterion would be necessary?

I think I would be able to prove it if I could show $\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow c} \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x,t) \, dt = \int_{a}^{\infty} \text{lim}_{x\rightarrow c} f(x,t) \, dt$, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: Your hypothesis is not strong enough. You not only need the continuity of $f(x,t)$, but you also need the integral to converge uniformly. If you look at Introduction to Analysis by William Wade, this is Theorem 11.8 on page 390.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get continuity, you need **for example** (this is not a necessary condition) $f(x, \cdot)$ integrable over $[a, +\infty[$ **and**:

$\forall (x, t) \in \mathbf{R} \times [a, +\infty[, \lvert f(x, t) \rvert \leq g(t)$ for some $g : [a, +\infty[ \to \mathbf{R}$ positive and integrable (notice that $g$ do not depend on $x$.)

In order to prove this, you can use dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Not true. Let $f(x,t)=\sqrt {x-a}$ for $a <t \leq a+\frac 1 {x-a}$, $0$ for $t \leq a$ as well as for $t >a+\frac 2 {x-a}$ and linear for $t$ in $(a+\frac 1 {x-a},a+\frac 2 {x-a})$. [Linear means the graphs is a straight line]. Then $F(a)=0$ and $F(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {x-a}}$ for $x>a$.

Comment: This wouldn't be bounded though, right? For $M \in \mathbf{R}^{+}$, if $(x,t) \in ( M^2 +a, 2M^2+a ) \times (a, a + \frac{1}{2M^2} )$, then $f(x,t) > M$, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually the problem though, considering the discontinuity occurs near x = a